# Spring elasticsearch filter terms consume list

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have the following index and query

```
@Document(indexName="idx", type="worker")
public class Worker {
    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Long)
    private Long id;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String firstName;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String lastName;
    --getter--setter
}


public interface WRepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<Worker, Long> {

    @Query("{
        "query": {"match": {"firstName": "?0"}},
        "filter": {"terms" : {"id" : ***ids***}}
    }")
    Page<Worker> searchWorker(String firstName, List<Long> ids, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Number of ids is changable,  when adding ids static like

*{"id" : [101, 102, 103]}*

it works as expected, my question is how can I pass id list from method signature like *firstName* field

*{"firstName": "?0"}*

Answer (score 0):

I changed method body below

```
@Query("{
    "query": {"match": {"firstName": "?0"}},
    "filter": {"terms" : {"id" : [?1]}}
}")
Page<Worker> searchWorker(String firstName, String ids, Pageable pageable);
```

and make my request as:

```
repository.searchProduct("firstName", "101,102", pageable)
```